cliente-servidor en python. fallo envio archivos
tengo un sistema cliente-servidor en python.
Básicamente quiero que los clientes puedan enviar archivos al servidor, y que este los almacene.
En principio parece que funciona bien, pero de repente el servidor muestra en consola el contenido del archivo y no lo almacena en el directorio indicado.
La consola del servidor en este punto muestra el siguiente mensaje:
     Mensaje inválido recibido de ('127.0.0.1', 40474): FILE log-02.log.csv 16284

A continuación puedo seguir enviando archivos y mensajes, funcionando correctamente, y llegado un punto, vuelve a fallar y
Alguien puede iluminarme, porque llevo varios días dándole vueltas.
Gracias de antemano
CLIENTE
 ```import socket
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import threading
import os

# Constantes
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # IP del servidor
PORT = 12345         # Puerto del servidor
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096   # Tamaño del buffer para la escritura de archivos

def start_client(server_host=HOST, server_port=PORT):
    """Función para iniciar el cliente."""
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((server_host, server_port))

    def send_message():
        message = message_entry.get()
        if message:
            client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            message_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

    def send_file():
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if file_path:
            filename = os.path.basename(file_path)  # Extraer solo el nombre del archivo
            filesize = os.path.getsize(file_path)  # Obtener el tamaño del archivo
            try:
                client_socket.send(f'FILE {filename} {filesize}'.encode('utf-8'))  # Enviar información del archivo
                
                with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                    bytes_sent = 0
                    while bytes_sent < filesize:
                        bytes_data = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)  # Leer el archivo en bloques
                        if not bytes_data:  # Si no hay más datos, salir
                            break
                        client_socket.send(bytes_data)  # Enviar los datos
                        bytes_sent += len(bytes_data)
                messagebox.showinfo("Info", f"Archivo {filename} enviado.")
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"No se pudo enviar el archivo: {e}")

    def receive_messages():
        while True:
            try:
                response = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
                message_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"Servidor: {response}")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error al recibir mensaje:", e)
                break

    # Interfaz gráfica
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Cliente")

    message_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, width=50, height=10)
    message_listbox.pack(pady=10)

    message_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
    message_entry.pack(pady=10)

    send_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enviar Mensaje", command=send_message)
    send_button.pack(pady=10)

    send_file_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enviar Archivo", command=send_file)
    send_file_button.pack(pady=10)  # Agregar el botón para enviar archivos

    threading.Thread(target=receive_messages, daemon=True).start()  # Iniciar el hilo para recibir mensajes
    
    root.mainloop()
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_client()

´´´
SERVIDOR
```import socket
import threading
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# Constantes
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # IP del servidor
PORT = 12345         # Puerto del servidor
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096   # Tamaño del buffer para la escritura de archivos

# Lista para almacenar los clientes y sus direcciones
clients = {}

# Crear la carpeta "RECIBIDOS" si no existe
if not os.path.exists('RECIBIDOS'):
    os.makedirs('RECIBIDOS')

def handle_client(client_socket, address):
    """Función para manejar la comunicación con el cliente."""
    print(f"Cliente conectado: {address}")
    while True:
        try:
            # Intentar recibir un mensaje del cliente
            message = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
            if not message:
                break  # El cliente ha cerrado la conexión
            
            if message.startswith('FILE'):
                parts = message.split(' ')
                if len(parts) != 3:
                    print(f"Mensaje inválido recibido de {address}: {message}")
                    continue  # Ignorar mensaje inválido
                
                filename = parts[1]
                filesize = int(parts[2])
                
                print(f"Recibiendo archivo: {filename} de tamaño {filesize} bytes")

                file_path = os.path.join('RECIBIDOS', filename)
                if os.path.exists(file_path):
                    print(f"El archivo {filename} ya existe, se omitirá.")
                    continue
                
                with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                    bytes_received = 0
                    while bytes_received < filesize:
                        bytes_data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        if not bytes_data:  # Si no hay más datos, salir
                            print("No se recibieron más datos. Cerrando conexión.")
                            break
                        f.write(bytes_data)
                        bytes_received += len(bytes_data)

                if bytes_received == filesize:
                    print(f"Archivo recibido y guardado: {file_path}")
                else:
                    print(f"Advertencia: se recibieron {bytes_received} bytes en lugar de {filesize} bytes.")
            else:
                print(f"[{address}] {message}")

            # Almacenar el cliente en el diccionario
            clients[address] = client_socket
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error al manejar el cliente {address}: {e}")
            break

    # Cerrar la conexión
    print(f"Cliente desconectado: {address}")
    del clients[address]
    client_socket.close()

def send_message_to_client(client_socket, message):
    """Envía un mensaje a un cliente específico."""
    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

def start_server(host=HOST, port=PORT):
    """Función para iniciar el servidor."""
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Servidor iniciado en {host}:{port}")

    threading.Thread(target=accept_clients, args=(server_socket,)).start()
    start_gui()

def accept_clients(server_socket):
    """Acepta clientes entrantes y los maneja en un hilo separado."""
    while True:
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, address)).start()

def start_gui():
    """Inicia la interfaz gráfica del servidor."""
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Servidor")

    def send_message():
        selected_client = client_listbox.curselection()
        if not selected_client:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Selecciona un cliente para enviar un mensaje.")
            return
        
        client_address = list(clients.keys())[selected_client[0]]
        message = message_entry.get()
        if message:
            send_message_to_client(clients[client_address], message)
            messagebox.showinfo("Info", f"Mensaje enviado a {client_address}: {message}")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Escribe un mensaje antes de enviar.")

    def update_client_list():
        client_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        for address in clients.keys():
            client_listbox.insert(tk.END, str(address))

    # Componentes de la GUI
    client_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, width=50)
    client_listbox.pack(pady=10)

    message_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
    message_entry.pack(pady=10)

    send_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enviar Mensaje", command=send_message)
    send_button.pack(pady=10)

    refresh_button = tk.Button(root, text="Actualizar Lista de Clientes", command=update_client_list)
    refresh_button.pack(pady=10)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
´´´


En tu servidor, haces:
if message.startswith('FILE'):
     parts = message.split(' ')
     if len(parts) != 3:
         print(f"Mensaje inválido recibido de {address}: {message}")
         continue  # Ignorar mensaje inválido

Incluso tienes el comentario agregado de Ignorar mensaje inválido
Te aconsejo 2 cosas:
#Prueba a limpiar el mensaje, de espacios adicionales al inicio y al final
message = message.strip()

#Imprime el mensaje antes del IF, para comprobar que es válido
print(f"Mensaje recibido: {message}")

Con esto ya deberías poder entender mejor tu problema, y agregar un control de errores más descriptivo.
Te dejo el fragmento completo para ayudar la depuración del error.
if message.startswith('FILE'):
    print(f"Mensaje recibido: {message}") # Sin strip
    message = message.strip()
    print(f"Mensaje strip: {message}") # Modificado
    parts = message.split(' ')
    print(f"Partes del mensaje: {parts}") # Partes resultantes
    
    if len(parts) != 3:
        print(f"Mensaje inválido recibido de {address}: {message}")
        continue  # Ignorar mensaje inválido

